# Subroutine & close record set hangs up while working from home

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subroutine that imports records from a store procedure (imports from a query to a temp table in access) and ever since I have been working from home, it hangs up and won't complete. I have a workaround where I set up a code-break for each record and then a break before rsTemp.Close, but this requires me to run the import instead of the end-user (It is only once a week and affects only one person who typically imports)

Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryValuationDef_Import", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Any general tips that might help with this issue as we continue to work from home?

Thank you

```
Sub FillValuationTable(ReportDate As Date)

Dim rsValID As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsSnap As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsTemp As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsDemand As DAO.Recordset
Dim ValId As Variant
Dim SnapID As Variant
Dim TimeStamp As Date
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
TimeStamp = Now()

If DCount("Deal_ID", "temp_GMSImport", "Selected=-1") > 0 Then 'Ensures that there are selected items to import

'Opens all applicable tables to write valuations to
Set rsValID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_dvsValuationDef", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set rsSnap = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_dvsGMSDealSnapshot", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryValuationDef_Import", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set rsDemand = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_dvsValuationDriver", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

rsTemp.MoveFirst

Do 'loops through all selected import items and writes them to the dvsValuationDef, dvsGMSDealSnapshot, and dvsValuationDriver table tables
With rsValID



'dvsValuationDef Additions
.AddNew
''Debug.Print rsValID
!dvsValuationDef_Descript = rsTemp("Link_Description")
''capture the description
Debug.Print !dvsValuationDef_Descript


!dvsBusinessUnit_Id = rsTemp("dvsBusinessUnit_Id")
!dvsBuySellType_Id = rsTemp("dvsBuySellType_Id")
!dvsValuationDef_Counterparty = rsTemp("Counterparty")
''Debug.Print !dvsValuationDef_Counterparty
!dvsValuationDef_DealTypePrice = rsTemp("Deal_Type_Price")
!dvsValuationDef_PipeBoardCode = rsTemp("Pipe_Board_Code")
!dvsValuationDef_ReportDate = ReportDate
!dvsRegion_Id = GetTraderRegion(DLookup("dvsTrader_Id", "dbo_dvsTrader", "dvsTrader_LastName=" & Chr(34) & rsTemp("Trader") & Chr(34)), rsTemp("Trader"), rsTemp("dvsRegion_Id"))
!dvsExecutive_Id = DLookup("dvsExecutive_Id", "lu_Region_SuperRegion_Exec", "dvsRegion_ID=" & rsTemp("dvsRegion_Id"))
!dvsDealType_Id = GetDealTypeID(rsTemp("Deal_Type_Price"))
!dvsCounterpartyType_Id = rsTemp("dvsCounterpartyType_Id")
!dvsValuationDef_HasAIPTrace = 0
!dvsValuationDef_HasRamp = 0
!dvsValuationDef_IsHidden = 0
!dvsValuationDef_HasAIPAdjust = 0
!dvsValuationDef_LastModified = TimeStamp
!dvsValuationDef_IsHidden = 0
!dvsValuationDef_TradeDate = rsTemp("Trade_Date")
.Update

.Bookmark = .LastModified
ValId = !dvsValuationDef_Id
''add to print the valuation number
Debug.Print ValId


End With



With rsSnap
'dvsGMSDealSnapshot additions
.AddNew
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_DealID = rsTemp("Deal_Id")
!dvsValuationDef_Id = ValId
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Trader = rsTemp("Trader")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_TradeDate = rsTemp("Trade_Date")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Region = rsTemp("Region")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_DealLink = rsTemp("Deal_Link_ID")
''Debug.Print !dvsGMSDealSnapshot_DealLink
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_LinkDescription = rsTemp("Link_Description")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_BusinessUnit = rsTemp("Business_Unit")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_BuySell = rsTemp("Buy_Sell")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Counterparty = rsTemp("Counterparty")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_DealTypePrice = rsTemp("Deal_Type_Price")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_PipeBoardCode = rsTemp("Pipe_Board_Code")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_IsAMA = rsTemp("AMA")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_IsToggle = rsTemp("Toggle")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_StartDate = rsTemp("Start_Date")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_StopDate = rsTemp("Stop_Date")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Quantity = rsTemp("Quantity")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_TotalDemand = rsTemp("Total_Demand")
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_LastModified = TimeStamp
.Update
.Bookmark = .LastModified
SnapID = !dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Id
''Debug.Print "snap ID" + SnapID
End With

With rsDemand
'dvsValuationDriver additions (this is Demand only)
.AddNew
!dvsValuationDriver_StartDate = rsTemp("Start_Date")
!dvsValuationDriver_StopDate = rsTemp("Stop_Date")
!dvsValuationDriver_Override = rsTemp("Total_Demand")
!dvsValuationDef_Id = ValId
!dvsGMSDealSnapshot_Id = SnapID
!dvsValuationDriverCat_Id = 3
!dvsValuationDriver_LastModified = TimeStamp
.Update
End With

'The following adds the trader to the Many to One table
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO dbo_dvsValuationDef_dvsTrader ( dvsTrader_Id, dvsValuationDef_Id )" & _
" SELECT " & Nz(rsTemp("dvsTrader_Id"), 0) & ", " & ValId & "; "


rsTemp.MoveNext
Loop Until rsTemp.EOF 'Loop until all the selected items for import are written correctly


rsTemp.Close
rsValID.Close
rsSnap.Close


End If
SequenceRowNumbers ReportDate
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Tables are stored inside the sane DataBase (embedded), linked to SQL Server, linked to another DataBase?

Comment: Temp tables in Access which are filled by the query against a SQL server DB

Comment: Consider re-writing this in TSQL so it runs in SQL Server, or else create an Access DB on the server in question, which negates the "lag" in data processing.

Comment: @Applecore, this is a good plan. I am trying to accept as the answer, but don't see a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to re-write this as a stored procedure within SQL Server, although this may take time depending on your TSQL skills.

A second option would be to create an Access database that is on the server in question. This database would have the correct tables from SQL Server linked, and you can then run your code in that database, rather than suffering the lag that you are currently experiencing.

Regards,